# assemble link programming ground up echo 0

Tags: linux, gcc, assembly

I'm using code here, https://github.com/foomur/programming-ground-up, I'm on a 64 bit pc,

i've installed 32 bit libs

`sudo apt-get install gcc-multilib`

what I use to assemble and link:

`as asm.asm -o asm.o && ld asm.o -o asm`

no errors from either assembler, linker, and exe `./asm`, but when I use
`echo $?` I get a return of `0` every time, which I think is an error.

I've tried other assembly code(code isn't the problem), and other assembler and link codes:
`as --32 asm.asm -o asm.o && ld -melf_i386 asm.o -o asm`
but I think thats an exe for a 32 bit processor(that also shows no errors but an echo of 0 everytime), I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I'm also running Ubuntu through a VM if that matters

Comment: Did you read the comment in the code? The one that says _"Should be 0, the exit status code"_? Yes, 0 is the correct exit code and that is not an error.

Comment: maximum.s should return 222 not 0

Comment: Don't put your Google Search in the title of your question.

Comment: Well you didn't say which code you tried, so I assumed the `exit.s`.

Comment: I dont know what the problem is it the assembler, linker, idk, therefore the title

Comment: By the way those programs are intended for 32 bit so you should use the second set of invocations to make them 32 bit. Although `maximum` does work in 64 bit mode too. Make sure you are not running anything between the `asm` and the `echo`. Best to write on a single line: `./asm; echo $?` Also make sure you actually compiled your `maximum` into `asm` and you don't accidentally still have the `exit` in there. Delete `asm` first and recompile and relink.

Comment: If all else fails, go back to `exit.s` and change the `movl $0, %ebx` to something other than zero to see if that works.

Comment: ``./asm`` wasn't opening in correct directory, it was opening an exe i made before i changed dir, which explains why i kept getting 0

Comment: You should be using `as --32 asm.asm -o asm.o && ld -melf_i386 asm.o -o asm`.  You even installed `gcc-multilib` so you could make 32-bit executables that use libc!  x86-64 CPUs can run 32-bit user-space and your kernel supports that.  You don't want to try to port the 32-bit examples to x86-64 until after you know enough asm to understand the differences (like `push` operand-size).  BTW, you can just use `gcc -m32 -static -nostdlib foo.s -o foo` to assemble + link exactly like you're doing manually, but with less typing (and only one option for 32 vs. 64-bit builds)